# How do I move a node's tags to be near its author information in my Bartik subtheme

Tags: theming, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I want to style a node's author data and tags slightly differently to the Bartik theme in Drupal 9.3. That is, rather than:

```
Submitted by user1 on Mon, 1/1/70
Tags
  foo
  bar
```

I'd like to have:

```
Submitted by user1 at Mon, 1/1/70 on foo | bar
```

So far, I have created a subtheme `tweak` with the following definition in `tweak.info.yml`:

```
name: Tweak
type: theme
description: This is a sub-theme of Bartik
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
base theme: bartik
version: '9.3.0'

regions:
  header: Header
  primary_menu: 'Primary menu'
  ...
```

I have copied the following templates into my subtheme and modified them:

```
templates/node.html.twig
templates/field--taxonomy-vocabulary-1.html.twig
```

I have enabled my subtheme and I can confirm that the overriding templates are being executed. That is, I get the following:

```
Submitted by user1 at Mon, 1/1/70
on foo | bar
```

Unfortunately, there is a lot of HTML in between the two lines, ie.

```
<span>
  Submitted by 
<span class="field field--name-uid field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden">
<span lang="" about="/user/2" typeof="schema:Person" property="schema:name" datatype="">user1</span>
</span>
at 
<span class="field field--name-created field--type-created field--label-hidden">Mon, 1/1/70 - 16:29</span>
</span>
    
</div>
  </header>
 <div class="node__content clearfix">
   <div class="field field--name-taxonomy-vocabulary-1 field--type-entity-reference field--label-above clearfix">
 on
  <a href="/taxonomy/term/7" hreflang="en">foo</a>
 | <a href="/taxonomy/term/2" hreflang="en">bar</a>
  </div>
```

What I'd like to have is the output from `field--taxonomy-vocabulary-1.html.twig` within the same `<div>` as the `Submitted by ...` content. However, I cannot see how to do that. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

@khummari's answer didn't work for me. However, I was able to adapt it.

I continued to use `field--taxonomy-vocabulary-1.html.twig` to theme the tags as I desired.

I then modified `node.html.twig` as follows. I used

```
{{ content.taxonomy_vocabulary_1 }}
```

to render the tags in my desired location. To prevent them rendering in their default location, I rendered the node's content as follows:

```
{{ content|without('taxonomy_vocabulary_1') }}
```

This feels like a bit of a hack though. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In node--article.html.twig override in your theme's template directory as follow

[image]

Then override the tags field twig template as follow

[image]

following should be the result

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for showing code. They are a hell to read on mobile and impossible to copy/paste. Please paste the code and use code-highlighting instead.

Comment: @khurrami thanks for the help. I've tried your suggestion and unfortunately `{{ content.field_tags }}` is rendering as empty in my case. Was there something else you changes that's not included in your answer?

Comment: Interestingly `{{content.taxonomy_vocabulary_1 }}` does render what I need. However, this is rendering in two places. I'm not sure how to turn the second (original) case off.